# awk failed to match the beginning and ending of a word

Tags: awk

I have encountered a problem. When I use awk to match the beginning and ending of words, it can be successful on centos, but it fails on ubuntu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssrgs.png)

`ip a | grep "\<inet\>"`
got the answer

`ip a | awk "/\<inet\>/{print $0}"`
No output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  Do not post links to images of text — that annoys people.  Embed the text directly in the question with a line containing only three back-ticks before it and only three back-ticks directly after it.

Comment: What is the expectation with the < and > ? Do you expect 'em to be there ?

Comment: The regular expressions recognized by [`awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) correspond to the [POSIX ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) (extended regular expression) notation.  The POSIX ERE notation does not include `\<` and `\>` to match the ends of words.  There are lots of subspecies of regex, and what works in one (e.g. `grep`) does not necessarily work in others (e.g. `awk`).

Comment: seems like you have `mawk`, you can install `gawk` for word boundary support... see also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046)

Comment: Thank you brother for answering. My problem has been solved.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  
Thanks for your suggestion, I am prompted when inserting a picture
"As soon as you earn 10 reputation on the site, you'll be able to embed images."
I will try to accumulate reputation

Comment: Don't insert images of text — even when you have enough reputation to do so.  Put text as text!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem has been solved, but how it has been solved has not been revealed.

Comment: I executed
"apt install gawk"
My awk is supported by gawk and I get the result I want

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm sorry I forgot to post it

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer (you are allowed to self-answer questions).  In due course (a day or two, IIRC), you can accept your answer if you've not received any alternatives that are more helpful.  Accepting your own answer won't give you any reputation points, but does indicate that this was the best way you knew of to solve your problem.  GNU Awk supports `\<` and `\>` as an extension.  As you already know, not all versions of Awk support it.  If portability is a concern, you avoid using extensions.  If it is not a problem, (a) you're lucky and (b) you can use extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Execute

```
file /etc/alternatives/awk
```

I see that my awk points to mawk.
mawk-its code base is based on the fast AWK implementation of the bytecode interpreter.
According to the previous suggestions, I installed gawk, This version is the standard implementation for Linux

```
apt install gawk
```

Execute again

```
file /etc/alternatives/awk
```

At this time the file has pointed to gawk,
Pointing to awk related commands again, I got the result I want